# ECG Diagram plot in HTML page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chart.js

In my project I need to plot, on web page, an ECG diagram.

My scenario is the following one: I have an ECG device connected to a mobile phone via bluetooth.
By using this device and relative SDK on Android I can plot diagram on my mobile by using data sent by the device.

On mobile device the heart wave is well plotted (by using device SDK for Android)

So far so good.

Generally speaking an ECG diagram is a diagram like this one

[image]

On server side I'm able in receiving data sent by the device and I'm using chartjs (version 2.9.3) in order to plot the diagram.

My result is this one:

[image]

As you can see it's not a clear ECG diagram (let's not focus on grid, I need to change them and use an image as background because in real ECG diagram the grid has x and y axis in millimeters)

By reading this diagram a doctor will think that basically it is a fibrillation heart diagram that is not real. I can't show the PQRST waves correctly.

I made the following assumptions:

- on X axis I'll put the time (but I'm not sure this is correct..)
- on Y axis I'll put the heart electric voltage measured by the ECG device and these measurements are correct

This is the code I wrote:

```
var chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)',
    black:'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
};
var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        //labels: [],
        datasets:
            [{
                backgroundColor: color(chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: chartColors.black,
                fill: false,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                data: []
            }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: ''
        },

        elements: {
            point:{
                radius: 0
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes:
            [{
                ticks: {

                    display: false, //this will remove only the label

        },
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgb(247, 174, 210)"
                           //color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
                },
                type: 'time',
                time:
                {
                    unit: 'seconds',
                    unitStepSize: '1'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgb(247, 174, 210)"
                    //color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
                },
                 ticks: {
                    /*max: 500,
                    min: 0,*/
                    stepSize:1,
                            display: false //this will remove only the label
                 }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: false,
        hover:false
    }
};
var context = $("#"+idEcg)[0].getContext('2d');
var ecgDiagram = new Chart(context, config);

var ecgDataFromServer = ..... //recover data from ecgDataFromServer.
//Note Every point has the following properties:
//tempo: it's the time when mobile device receives the measurement
//tensione: it's the heart electric voltage measured
for( var t = 0; t < ecgDataFromServer.length; t++ ){
var ecgDataPoint = ecgDataFromServer[t];
chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push({
  x: new Date(ecgDataPoint.tempo),
  y: ecgDataPoint.tensione
});
}
chart.update({
  preservation: true
});
```

I'm stucked on this diagram from several days and I can't figure how I can represent as I wish.

I can't find some formula that eventually allows to me to make a good data interpolation.

Now I'm evaluating to use d3.js as library (but I'm very new to it and I need to learn it; this is the reason I put d3.js tag as well).

I may also use some server side strategy (in java, matalab, R or any other) in order to generate a PNG o JPG image of the diagram and represents it.

Can anyone suggest to me if what I need it's feasible?

How can I plot my diagram like the ecgDiagram I showed?

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: Regarding D3 the answer (*"it's feasible?"*) depends on the data, more specifically on the quality and structure of your data. Be it SVG or canvas, D3 will create that path interpolating data points. For the QRS complex that's not a problem (they are almost lines anyway), but for the P and T bumps (and for the P-R/S-T segments) that will be definitely an issue. Also, by quickly seeing your image, I'd say that you have to stretch the x axis.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thank you for answering. I was thinking about d3 because I saw this example https://bl.ocks.org/Berzeg/3909a8234433d8079211a2145a56b21c but I need to deeply study it and the framework as well; tha bad thing is that I'm not able in finding the right algorithm for the P and T bumps... they seem to be like sinusoidal but I'm not able in plotting them correctly

Comment: Hello, @AngeloImmediata. Any solutions?

Comment: The only difference is the grid: in the first example ecg has a square grid, in the second example not. The ecg is usually represented with graph paper, usually with paper speed 25 mm/sec. and voltage gain 10 mm/mV.